# Setting a different seed for each run of the code

Tags: python, numpy, torch, random-seed

I am running a code that could potentially benefit from different initialization(s) of random number generators. I use libraries `torch` and `python`. I am using the following lines of code to set random seed at the beginning of every iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

seed = np.random.randint(0, 1000)
print(f"Seed: {seed}")
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
```

For some reason though, across (many) iterations I have observed that the seed is always set to one value, `688` in my case. What I do not understand is that the generation of the `seed` variable is not governed by the seed that is set later. So why does the same seed get set every time and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - random works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you initialize the default random number generator implicitly by not calling and providing seed for the RandomState class. In such cases, NumPy obtains an [alternative source for the seed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) which may be not random enough.

Furthermore, it is not considered as a good practice to [generate a random number on a small set of numbers and use it to seed the random number generator](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/01/29/random-number-generator-seed-mistakes/), because the probability that you'll generate the same seed is high. However, if you have similar seed values and a not too good initialization, it is a common practice to use a fast, tiny, but maybe not too good random number generator to create good quality seed values, or the whole initial state itself. But there is no need to do it manually, because NumPy's legacy random implementation follows [a specific case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Initialization) of a scientifically sound approach [1] that ensures good different initial states even on similar (e.g. adjacent) seed values. I.e. you can seed your simulations with 0 to 1000, and the random numbers you get with NumPy in the different iterations will look completely different. You can also use this seed value to identify your calculation when you save it, or when you create statistics.

I am not sure about the implementation of random number generator in torch though. It seems [it takes a 64-bit integer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.manual_seed.html). If it suits your need, you can generate random numbers with NumPy's engine on this range and use at as a seed value. If you make 2 simulations, the probability that the 2 seed values are the same is 1/2^{64} ~ 5 * 10^{-20}.

With the example below, it is ensured that the state of NumPy's random generator is different in each iteration of the `for` loop, and the random state of `torch` is most probably different in each iteration
.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

max_sim = 3  # how many simulations you need

for numpy_seed in range(max_sim):
    np.random.seed(numpy_seed)
    torch_seed = np.random.randint(low=-2**63,
                                   high=2**63,
                                   dtype=np.int64)
    print(torch_seed)
    torch.manual_seed(torch_seed)
    # do the rest of the simulation

# output:
# 900450186894289455
# -1530673954295414549
# -1180685649882019313
```

[1]: Matsumoto, Makoto and Wada, Isaku and Kuramoto, Ai and Ashihara, Hyo,
Title: Common Defects in Initialization of Pseudorandom Number Generators; around equation 30

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your result as well like @iacob, and I believe the script to set the seed has no problem.
[image]